# trigger to update table contribution calculation using mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, calculation

I need to calculate contribution base on project per developer

```
Contribution table
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id | projected | developer id | total hours | contribution|
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         |  1           |      25     |             |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1         |  2           |      75     |             |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 2         |  1           |      10     |             |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

need to update same table with trigger after insert and update 
expected result

```
  Contribution table
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    | id | projected | developer id | total hours | contribution|
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    | 1  | 1         |  1           |      25     |   25%       |
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    | 2  | 1         |  2           |      75     |   75%       |
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    | 3  | 2         |  1           |      10     |   100%      |
    -------------------------------------------------------------
```

> calculation for the getting contribution
>
> project 1 :
>             total hours = 25 + 75 = 100
>             contribution per developer = 25/100*100
>                                        = 25%

i need a trigger to get this result: but don't know how to get this

This is my trigger not getting error but contribution calculation not correct

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `update_contribution` AFTER INSERT ON `tasks`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
 IF NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT p_id ,d_id 
  FROM contribution 
  WHERE 
  p_id = NEW.p_id 
  AND 
  d_id = NEW.d_id) 
  THEN

 SET @old_total_dev_hours = (SELECT SUM(total_hours)             
                       FROM contribution 
                       WHERE p_id = NEW.p_id
                       GROUP BY p_id);


 SET @total_hours1 = (SELECT (total_hours)             
                       FROM contribution 
                       WHERE d_id = NEW.d_id AND p_id = NEW.p_id
                       );

  SET @dev_con =  @total_hours1/@old_total_dev_hours*100 ;

  SET @total_hours =  new.hours + new.overtime;
  INSERT INTO contribution
    ( p_id,
     d_id,
     hours,
     overtime,
     total_hours,
     contribution
    )
   VALUES
   (NEW.p_id,
    NEW.d_id,
    NEW.hours,
    NEW.overtime,
      @total_hours ,
    @dev_con
   );
 ELSE
   UPDATE contribution 
   SET 
   hours = hours + NEW.hours , 
   overtime = overtime + NEW.overtime, 
   total_hours = hours + overtime,
   contribution = @dev_con
   WHERE 
   p_id = NEW.p_id 
   AND 
   d_id = NEW.d_id;
   END IF;
   END
```

> This is my code in this code other calculation are working fine
>   contribution is not getting correctly!!

Comment: Instead of trigger and updating a summary table, why not just use queries against the first table to get your results?

Comment: This could have been calculated in the trigger in your other question when the contribution record is initially inserted.

Comment: requirement is build a trigger to update contribution on the table

Comment: can you can build  previous trigger to get this result same time ? i have no idea how to do it

Comment: You previous question on this topic mentioned a tasks table (you should have brought this into this question) but I wasn't clear to me what information tasks held or how it was maintained. Does tasks capture the hours that a developer has spent on a project? And are there many entries per programmer/task (ie many inserts)? And can tasks be UPDATEd as well as INSERTed?

Comment: forget the previous one  can i get a new solution for this i need to get contribution using above calculation on update/ insert both

Comment: Your question makes no sense if viewed in isolation and the previous question did not make a lot of sense without an expansion on the role that tasks has to play.

Comment: i update my code its working but contribution not correct

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated trigger that would replace the one from your previous question. It calculates
both values for the total_hours and contribution percentage.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER update_hours AFTER INSERT ON tasks
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET @old_total_dev_hours = (SELECT SUM(hours + overtime)
        FROM contribution 
        WHERE p_id == new.p_id && d_id == new.d_id 
        GROUP BY p_id,d_id);
    SET @old_total_hours = (SELECT SUM(hours + overtime)
        FROM contribution 
        WHERE p_id == new.p_id
        GROUP BY p_id);

    SET @total_hours = @old_total_dev_hours + new.hours + new.overtime;
    SET @contrib_percent = (@old_total_dev_hours / @old_total_hours) * 100;

    INSERT INTO contribution
    ( p_id,
    d_id,
    hours,
    overtime,
    total_hours,
    contribution )
    VALUES
    ( 
        NEW.p_id,
        NEW.d_id,
        NEW.hours,
        NEW.overtime,
        @total_hours,
        @contrib_percent
    );
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I don't have a way to test it. What is the full text of the error message?

Comment: i update my code its working but contribution not correct

Comment: Telling me it's incorrect isn't very helpful by itself. What is wrong? Be specific. Or look at how it's calculated and fix it.

Comment: your code not worked but using that code i build a new trigger now its working find thanks to you

Comment: i updated working code check it but contribution  calculation not correct

Comment: Again, telling me "not correct" without explaining what isn't correct isn't very helpful. Explain what isn't correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170066/discussion-between-shawty-and-sloan-thrasher).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming tasks logs hours worked by developers on projects then 2 things can happen 1) there is no note that a developer has worked on a project in contribution 2) a developer has worked on a project and the hours he has worked need to updated in contribution. Both cases imply that all developer contributions need to be recalculated on each insert to tasks.

For example

```
drop table if exists t,contribution;
create table t(id int auto_increment primary key, developerid int, projectid int,hrs_normal int, hrs_overtime int);
create table contribution(id int auto_increment primary key, projectid int,
developerid int, hrs int, contribution decimal (6,3) default 0);

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on t
for each row 
begin
declare totalhours int default 0;
    set totalhours = (select ifnull(sum(hrs),0) from contribution where projectid = new.projectid);
    set totalhours = totalhours + ifnull(new.hrs_normal,0) + ifnull(new.hrs_overtime,0);
    if not exists (select 1 from contribution where projectid = new.projectid and developerid = new.developerid) then
        insert into contribution(projectid,developerid,hrs) 
        values
        (new.projectid,new.developerid,ifnull(new.hrs_normal,0) + ifnull(new.hrs_overtime,0)
        );
    else 
        update contribution
            set hrs = hrs + ifnull(new.hrs_normal,0) + ifnull(new.hrs_overtime,0)
            where developerid = new.developerid and projectid = new.projectid;
    end if;

    update contribution
        set contribution = (hrs / totalhours) * 100
        where projectid = new.projectid;

end $$
delimiter ;

MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table contribution;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from contribution;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t (developerid , projectid ,hrs_normal , hrs_overtime )
    -> values
    -> (1,1,10,0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| id | developerid | projectid | hrs_normal | hrs_overtime |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|  1 |           1 |         1 |         10 |            0 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from contribution;
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
| id | projectid | developerid | hrs  | contribution |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
|  1 |         1 |           1 |   10 |      100.000 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t (developerid , projectid ,hrs_normal , hrs_overtime )
    -> values
    -> (1,1,10,0),(2,1,30,10);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| id | developerid | projectid | hrs_normal | hrs_overtime |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|  1 |           1 |         1 |         10 |            0 |
|  2 |           1 |         1 |         10 |            0 |
|  3 |           2 |         1 |         30 |           10 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from contribution;
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
| id | projectid | developerid | hrs  | contribution |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
|  1 |         1 |           1 |   20 |       33.333 |
|  2 |         1 |           2 |   40 |       66.667 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t (developerid , projectid ,hrs_normal , hrs_overtime )
    -> values
    -> (1,1,10,0),(2,2,30,10);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| id | developerid | projectid | hrs_normal | hrs_overtime |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|  1 |           1 |         1 |         10 |            0 |
|  2 |           1 |         1 |         10 |            0 |
|  3 |           2 |         1 |         30 |           10 |
|  4 |           1 |         1 |         10 |            0 |
|  5 |           2 |         2 |         30 |           10 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from contribution;
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
| id | projectid | developerid | hrs  | contribution |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
|  1 |         1 |           1 |   30 |       42.857 |
|  2 |         1 |           2 |   40 |       57.143 |
|  3 |         2 |           2 |   40 |      100.000 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note if the business rules are that a developers hours can amended in tasks you will also need and update trigger along the same lines.